# In QuestDB how to efficiently query all the data for time range between 14:30 and 21:00 any day?

Tags: questdb

I am trying to get all rows across 1 month where the **time_of_day** is between 14:30 and 21:00. I tried the below

```sql
SELECT 
  extract(hour from timestamp), 
  extract(minute from timestamp),
  *
from 
  trades 
where 
((extract(hour from timestamp) >= 14 and extract(minute from timestamp) <= 30)
 and (extract(hour from timestamp) <= 21 and extract(minute from timestamp) >= 0))
 and timestamp in '2024-02'
```

but it didn't work I see the data with 21:30 times in it. What's the best syntax to query the time interval of the day and ideally avoid full table scan?